# Interchanging integral and sum of a divergent series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation, divergent-series, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I am trying to compute the following integral:

\begin{equation}
\int_{x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3}\sum_{\vec{0}\neq\vec{n}\in Z^3}\sum_{\vec{0}\neq\vec{m}\in Z^3} \frac{m_1n_1}{\vec{n}^2\vec{m}^2}e^{i2\pi\vec{n}\cdot\left(x_1,x_2,y_3\right)+i2\pi\vec{m}\cdot\left(x_1,y_2,x_3\right)} dx^1dx^2dx^3dy^1dy^2dy^3\, ,
\end{equation}

where the integral goes from $0$ to $1$ for all variables $x^i$, $y^i$;  $\vec n=(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ and the same for $\vec m$. I have been reading about interchanging the sum and the integral and I am not sure if I can do it in this case. If this was possible, then I do know how to proceed, so my question is if I can first do the integral and afterwards the sum, this is:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\vec{0}\neq\vec{n}\in Z^3}\sum_{\vec{0}\neq\vec{m}\in Z^3}\frac{m_1n_1}{\vec{n}^2\vec{m}^2}\int_{x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3} e^{i2\pi\vec{n}\cdot\left(x_1,x_2,y_3\right)+i2\pi\vec{m}\cdot\left(x_1,y_2,x_3\right)} dx^1dx^2dx^3dy^1dy^2dy^3\, .
\end{equation}

If the answer is no, what is happening then? Is it the result divergent -I know the series is-? Can I just argue that I am 'renormalising' the result in some sense?

Comment: You seem to say you know that the *original* integra**nd** is a divergent sum. What is the question then? What are you computing? (The *result* of the interchange is clearly *convergent*; most of the integrals vanish.)

Comment: (There *is* a way to interpret the sum in the [distributional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) sense, when even [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) things are perfectly valid; but that's a completely different story, and your question doesn't mention anything like that.)

Comment: the question is if the convergent  result obatined by interchanging the sum and the integral really  makes  sense (beacuse I do not know if this interchange can be done) or if the integral is also divergent